# How to sort JSONArray in android

Tags: java, android, json

How to sort JSONArray by its Tag name with ascending and descending on android.

In my application i have a JSON like the following and need to display the data according to users option(sorting by user_id tag in ascending or descending order). I have parsed the JSON as the following:

```
JSONObject mObject = new JSONObject(JSONResponse);
String commentsVal = mObject.getString("message");
String resultVal = mObject.getString("result");
JSONArray resultArray = new JSONArray(resultVal);
int resultSize = resultArray.length();
for (int i = 0; i < resultArray.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject resultObj = resultArray.getJSONObject(i);
    resultObj.getString("comment_id");
    .....
}
..............
```

and this is my JSON response:

```
{
"success": 1,
"message": "some message",
"result": [
    {
        "comment_id": "43906",
        "comp_id": "116725",
        "user_id": "48322",
        "agree": "0",
        .....
        "replies": [....]
    },
    {
        "comment_id": "43905",
        "comp_id": "116725",
        "user_id": "48248",
        "agree": "0",
        .......
        "replies": [...]
    }
]

}
```

I need the "result" JSON Array sorted by the "user_id" tag name while parsing, how to do it in Android?

Comment: are you saving that response somewhere in sqlite or just showing the whole content on a view?

Comment: why do you need to sort during the parsing ? you can order after the parsing. using collections.sort for instance

Comment: I have save the each object in each individual arraylist. if i sort the user_id arraylist other the values are disordered. that is the problem i am facing.

Comment: are you telling me that you store every single object inside a different ArrayList?

Comment: yes, I am storing every single object inside a different ArrayList.

Comment: please take a look at my [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39952230/after-sorting-jsonarray-custom-list-view-not-changed) ..same issue

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
public static JSONArray sortJsonArray(JSONArray array) {
    List<JSONObject> jsons = new ArrayList<JSONObject>();
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
        jsons.add(array.getJSONObject(i));
    }
    Collections.sort(jsons, new Comparator<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(JSONObject lhs, JSONObject rhs) {
            String lid = lhs.getString("comment_id");
            String rid = rhs.getString("comment_id");
            // Here you could parse string id to integer and then compare.
            return lid.compareTo(rid);
        }
    });
    return new JSONArray(jsons);
}
```

This piece of code could return a sorted JSONArray, but i still recommend you to parse JSONObject to your own data beans, and then do the sorting on them.

Comment: your code for is working. but the compareTo do descending order. what should i change for ascending order?

Comment: @murali_ma change lid.compareTo(rid) to rid.compareTo(lid)

Comment: please take a look at my [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39952230/after-sorting-jsonarray-custom-list-view-not-changed) ..same issue

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me like the easiest way to do it, rather than "sorting the JSON Array" as you suggest, is to just parse the whole thing into a data structure which contains the information like so:

```
class Results {
     String user_id;
     Strung comment_id;
}
```

Save this as an ArrayList or a [insert favourite List structure].

Once you've parsed the entire JSON Array, you can then sort your ArrayList based on the user_id field using `Collections.sort`, giving you them in order

Answer (score 0):

Following code may useful to you.

```
ArrayList<ResultBean> user_array;
Collections.sort(user_array, new Comparator<ResultBean>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(ResultBean data1, ResultBean data2) {
        if (data1.getUserId() >= data2.getUserId()) {
            return -1;
        } else {
            return 1;
        }
    }
});
```

Your `ResultBean` will look like following.

```
public class ResultBean {
    //other methods and declarations...
    public int getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }
}
```