# How to sort multi dimentional JsonArray in android

Tags: android, json, sorting

I have a JSONArray like the following and i need to sort it by id_cat tag in ascending order.

```
{
 "item_cat": [
       {
         "82": {
                 "name": [
                     {
                        "id_cat":"2",
                        "name_cat": "red"
                     }
                ],
                 "data":[...]
         },
         "83":{    
                "name":[
                    {
                        "id_cat":"3",
                        "name_cat":"black"        
                    }
                ],
                  "data":[...]
         },
         "84": {
                 "name": [
                     {
                        "id_cat":"4",
                        "name_cat": "green"
                     }
                ],
                 "data":[...]
         },
       }
   ]
 }
```

I have succesfully parsed the JSON but the order is not apropriate.
I have try to sorting it using collections.sort like the following [json array discussed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17697568/how-to-sort-jsonarray-in-android)

EDIT,
here is my code:

```
...
JSONArray ikatarray = ikat.getJSONArray("item_cat");                            
List<JSONObject> jsons1 = new ArrayList<JSONObject>();

for (int cb = 0; cb < ikatarray.length(); cb++) {
    JSONObject cd = ikatarray.getJSONObject(cb);

    Iterator ikatkeys = cd.keys();
        while (ikatkeys.hasNext()) {
            String item = (String) ikatkeys.next();                             
            JSONObject data = cd.getJSONObject(item);                                                                   
            JsonArray name = data.getJSONArray("name");                                                 
            ArrayList<JSONObject> jsons = new ArrayList<JSONObject>();

                for (int c = 0; c < name.length(); c++) {                                                       
                    jsons.add(name.getJSONObject(c));
                    Collections.sort(jsons, new Comparator<JSONObject>() {
                        @Override
                        public int compare(JSONObject lhs,JSONObject rhs) {
                        String lid = null;
                            try {
                                lid = lhs.getString("id_cat");
                            } catch (JSONException e) {                                                         
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                                String rid = null;
                            try {
                                rid = rhs.getString("id_cat");
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }                                           
                            return lid.compareTo(rid);
                        }
                        });

                JSONArray a = new JSONArray(jsons);                                                                                                             

                for (int b = 0; b < a.length(); b++) {
                    JSONObject k = a.getJSONObject(b);
                    String namecat = k.getString("name_cat");

                    Log.d("print: ", namecat.toString());

                    TextView labelName = new TextView(
                    Tabel2.this);
                    labelName.setId(200 + count);
                    labelName.setText(namecat);
                    labelName.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
                    labelName.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                    tr.addView(labelName);
                    }
                }
            }   
        }
    }
```

the output from logcat:

```
Log.d("print: ", jsons.toString());
-----------------log cat ---------------
print: [{"id_cat":"2","name_cat":"red"}]
print: [{"id_cat":"4","name_cat":"green"}]
print: [{"id_cat":"3","name_cat":"black"}]
```

how is the possible way to do that?

Comment: Where is your code ? What have you tried?

Comment: instead to do sorting at your end. Please make it on server from which data is coming, As it a simple task using sql query.

Comment: @vivek, maybe he doesn't control the server. Also  OP you should add all the items first and then sort them. Now your adding an item and sorting each time. You should not do that. You should also reconsider your logic here

Comment: @ElefantPhace, did you mean i have to concate all item before sorting them?