# How to sort list in RecyclerView on Android

Tags: java, android, sorting, android-recyclerview

In my application i want add some data from server into **adapter** of `RecyclerView`.
I write below codes and i can get data from server and show into `RecyclerView`.
But my json in **not sorted** with **Alphabet** from server.
I want before add this data into `ArrayList`, **first** sort this with **Alphabet** and add into `ArrayList`.
**My json :**

```
{
    "validationCheckResult": {
        "isValid": true,
        "message": "Success"
    },
    "internalCarBoard": [{
        "id": 0,
        "name": “S500”,
        "companyName": “Benz”,
    }, {
        "id": 0,
        "name": " E250”,
        "companyName": “Benz”,
    }, {
        "id": 0,
        "name": “TT”,
        "companyName": “Audi”,
    }, {
        "id": 0,
        "name": " Talisman”,
        "companyName": “Renult”,
    }, {
        "id": 0,
        "name": " Accord”,
        "companyName": “Honda”,
    }, {
        "id": 0,
        "name": “A8”,
        "companyName": “Audi”,
    }]
}
```

I want sort above json from **companyName** with **Alphabet** before add to `ArrayList`.
But i want sort this into **Android** not **server**.

**My Java codes:**

```
public class SortListActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RecyclerView sortList_recycler;
    private SortAdapter sortAdapter;
    private List<InternalCarBoard> model = new ArrayList<>();
    private API api;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sort_list);
        sortList_recycler = findViewById(R.id.sortList_recycler);
        api = ApiClient.getClient().create(API.class);
        sortAdapter = new SortAdapter(model);
        sortList_recycler.setHasFixedSize(true);
        sortList_recycler.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        sortList_recycler.setAdapter(sortAdapter);

        Call<VersionUpdateResponse> call = api.getCar();
        call.enqueue(new Callback<VersionUpdateResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<VersionUpdateResponse> call, Response<VersionUpdateResponse> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    if (response.body() != null) {
                        if (response.body().getInternalCarBoard().size() > 0) {
                            model.clear();
                            model.addAll(response.body().getInternalCarBoard());
                            sortAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<VersionUpdateResponse> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

How can i sort json with **Alphabet** from **companyName** before add into `ArrayList`?

Comment: use Java 8 stream API sort

Comment: @GaneshPatil, how can i it? can you help me and send to me code with my above codes? because i am amateur

Comment: ok sure.........

Comment: using collection sort you can do it 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12901742/android-how-to-sort-jsonarray-of-jsonobjects

Comment: @WaleedAsim, can you send to me code with my above codes? because i am amateur. please

Comment: Here is the code:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17697568/how-to-sort-jsonarray-in-android/17698236

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5815423/sorting-arraylist-in-alphabetical-order-case-insensitive
 also see this

Comment: @WaleedAsim, can you send to me code with my above codes? i am amateur. please

Comment: @Hock please check my answer

Comment: Collections.sort(response.body().getInternalCarBoard());

Comment: you are using retrofit for api calls , so along with retrofit you can use rx and sort  get the sorted respoonse

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use Collections.sort() like this

```
Collections.sort(model, new Comparator<InternalCarBoard>(){
            public int compare(InternalCarBoard obj1, InternalCarBoard obj2) {
                // ## Ascending order
                return obj1.getCompanyName().compareToIgnoreCase(obj2.getCompanyName); // To compare string values
                // return Integer.valueOf(obj1.getId()).compareTo(obj2.getId()); // To compare integer values

                // ## Descending order
                // return obj2.getCompanyName().compareToIgnoreCase(obj1.getCompanyName()); // To compare string values
                // return Integer.valueOf(obj2.getId()).compareTo(obj1.getId()); // To compare integer values
            }
        });
```

check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9109890/android-java-how-to-sort-a-list-of-objects-by-a-certain-value-within-the-object) for details.

Comment: But i want another question, can i sort first with companyName , then sort name. then add into recyclerView

Comment: you can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4805606/how-to-sort-by-two-fields-in-java) link

Answer (score 0):

Please try following java 8 sorting API it will sort by ascending order

before adding to your new list

```
yourlist.sort((object1,object2)->object1.getCompanyName().compareTo(object2.getCompanyName())); // sort

yourlist.forEach(action->System.out.println(action.getCompanyName())); //iterate
```

Answer (score 0):

Sort your data before adding it to `Adapter`. You can try `Collections.sort()`

You can check this: [How to sort RecyclerView item in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45790363/how-to-sort-recyclerview-item-in-android)

```
Collections.sort(response.body().getInternalCarBoard(), new Comparator<InternalCarBoard>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(InternalCarBoard x, InternalCarBoard y) {
            // -1 - less than, 1 - greater than, 0 - equal, all inversed for descending
            return x.companyName > y.companyName;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks but i am amateur :( can you send to me code with my above codes? please :9